# Nextjs13: loading.tsx files fallback on their ancestors and glitch

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js13, react-server-components

I'm trying to build a simple app with Nextjs 13.4.9, and there's this weird behaviour I'm facing among `loading.tsx` files while navigating between routes. It seems like when I navigate to a route which has a corresponding `loading.tsx` file, instead of imidiately showing the corresponding `loading.tsx` file from the route segment, for a split  second it shows the `loading.tsx` file from its parent route.

- app

  - products

    - laptop

      - `page.tsx`
      - `loading.tsx`
    - smart-watch

      - `page.tsx`
      - `loading.tsx`
    - `page.tsx`
    - `loading.tsx`

So basically in a routing structure like above, when I navigate between `/products/smart-watch` and `/products/laptop`, for a brief moment is shows the `loading.tsx` file from `products` and then it switches to the `loading.tsx` file from the route I'm trying to visit.
My code is as simple as it gets and they're all Server Components.
has anybody faced something like this ? Is it a bug or am I just missing something ?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: What if you give them unique names? Same thing still happen?

Comment: @MStodd Already done that. Still the same. Doesn't this happen to you in a similar routing structure ?

Answer (score 0):

U can add 'layout.tsx' in child folder, ie can help load 'loading.tsx' from parent folder.

---

### folder structure

- app

  - laptop

    - layout.tsx
    - loading.tsx
    - page.tsx
  - smart-watch

    - layout.tsx
    - loading.tsx
    - page.tsx
  - header.tsx
  - loading.tsx

app/products/page.tsx

```
const Page = async () => {

    // wait 3 second
    async function taketime () {
        await new Promise((resolve) => { 
        setTimeout(resolve,3000);
        });
    }
    await taketime();

    return (
        <>
            <p>Product Home Page.</p>
        </>
    );
}

export default Page;
```

app/prodcuts/laptop/layout.tsx

```
interface LayoutProps {
    children: () => void;
}

const Layout = async ({children}:LayoutProps) => {

    // Wait 3 secound
    async function taketime () {
        await new Promise((resolve) => { 
        setTimeout(resolve,3000);
        });
    }
    await taketime();

    return (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout;
```

app/products/laptop/page.tsx

```
import { Header } from "../header";

const Page = async () => {

    // wait 6 second
    async function taketime () {
        await new Promise((resolve) => { 
        setTimeout(resolve,6000);
        });
    }
    await taketime();

    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <p>Product - Laptop Details.</p>
        </>
    );
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: I just tried your solution, but unfortunately the glitch still remains. The problem is not that the individual loading.tsx files don't load at all, the problem is the the parent loading.tsx file flashes for a moment before the correct loading.tsx file show up.